# How to compress game data in one file

Tags: c, zip, compression, zlib

I'm trying to make game like "Duke Nukem 3D". I will have many maps in my game and each map will have it's **own** (and no more!) data files such as textures, sounds and so on, that's why I need to compress all these data files to one "map" file.

So, let's image that I want to test my maps one by one, and after compiling my code I want to test my first map with her textures and sounds, And when I type in my command line something like this: ./game_name "mymap.rce" or ./game_name "mymap.zip" my game must start with map what I typed and this map must have textures and sounds which I compressed with her.

You can download demo [here](https://projects.intra.42.fr/uploads/document/document/149/demo.tgz).

To run demo you can type this for example: ./rce demo1.rce

Comment: I don’t see the problem? Specify a format and place all the data in one file.

Comment: @Fredrik and how to read it in c?)

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm

Comment: @Fredrik I can use only syscalls functions such as open, read, write.

Comment: Or just go with a zip file and use a library to open that.

Comment: @Fredrik, on assignment I can use only [syscalls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

Comment: So? What problem do you have? Is it reading files?

Comment: For reading, say a texture's data, is it OK to extract it as a file from the Zip archive, then to read the file? Or you would like to read the data without writing a temp file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just made my archiver(without compress). If you need it, you can find it [here](https://gitlab.com/ramory-l/rammer).